# What is the difference between SQL Server standard and web edition?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any technical difference between these 2 editions or is it just how they are licenced?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here you can find a comprehensive comparison :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28SQL.105%29.aspx

Please note: the Web edition does come with SQL Profiler and management studio

Comment: [The Web edition 2012 and 2014 don't come with SQL Profiler anymore.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx)

Answer (score 43):

Since newer version(s) of SQL Server have been released, the feature comparison is tucked away in MSDN:

- [SQL Server 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [SQL Server 2017](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017)
- [SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.140).aspx)
- [SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx)
- [SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Any chance we could get a link for SQL Server 2017?

Answer (score 23):

They're close, but not quite the same.  The primary difference is the licensing (as you mention).  The other differences are around mirroring (web can only serve as a witness), publishing (web can only subscribe), and performance (web does not come with SQL Profiler).

There are more differences when you get out of the SQL Engine and into SSIS, SSAS, and SSRS.

Full comparison of all editions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

Comment: Can you elaborate tuning part of SQL server web edition 2019?